# Should I say "I spend most of my time on Facebook" or "I spend most of the time on Facebook"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Should I say "I spend most of my time on Facebook" or "I spend most of the time on Facebook"?

Or both are correct?

Answer (score 1):

*Both* are correct, but each may be suitable in different situations.

"My time" is obviously unique to yourself - it isn't anybody else's time. Idiomatically though, "my time" often refers to your *spare* time. If you said "I spend my time on Facebook", it would not be assumed that you spend every minute, 24 hours a day on it - you have to eat and sleep, and probably work or go to school. It would be understood that is how you spend your spare, or leisure time (or a large amount of it).

When you use the definite article "*the*", you are referring to something *specific*. It should be obvious to your audience what that specific something is - for example, if you referred to "*the car*" they would need to know *which car* you meant, as there are many cars.

Saying "I spend *the* time" wouldn't make much sense without any context, but if you have already referred to a specific time then it would be clear that is what you are referring to. For example:

> Every evening I have to wait 15 minutes for my bus to arrive. I spend the time on Facebook.

It seems clear in this example that *the time* you refer to is that 15 minutes you spend waiting for your bus.

Answer (score 0):

> **I spend most of my time on Face book**.
>
> **I spend most of the time on Face book**.

I think both the sententences are correct   and mean almost the same thing in the context.

We use article *the* in the sense of *my*

*He kicked me by the neck*.Here **the** refers to  **my**

**He pinched me by the ear**.

Anyhow, you spend most of your time on Face book.